# Mosfet transistor circuit verification

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I have circuit where I am using transisitor [2N3904](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/2N3904.pdf) and Mosfet [IRF9540](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91078/91078.pdf). Following is the schematic:

[image]

In the above circuit, `chargePin` is the digital pin of Atmega328p(arduino uno). `Solar+` is the pin where solar voltage is coming. `Battery+` is the battery voltage pin. So depending upon the few conditions, MCU will enable the `chargePin` which will enable the transistor and then Mosfet will connect the solar voltage to battery voltage to start charging. But what's happening is, chargePin is disabled but still the solar+ is connected to battery+.

Is there any error in the above circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should horizontally flip the MOSFET, so source will be on solar output. MOSFET is controlled by VGS, which should not depend on output. ALso depending on voltage you may need another resistor between gate and T1 collector, so VDS would remain in certain range.

Comment: The gate  is closest to the source in any FET symbol. Flipped YES but so source will be on battery NO. The source is the Solar+ input.

Comment: Also it may depend on output if fully charged, by control function but I know you meant by Vgs control voltage

Comment: May. But i am pretty sure that this is not what he means. Judging by the question

Comment: perhaps you can correct your answer

Comment: "another resistor between gate and T1 collector" that, and/or zener diode to limit the Vgs of Q2.